# opening and looking for a word in a .dic file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text input field that the user is going to enter a word then click a button and I want the user to get an output of true or false (True: if the word is correct,  False: else..) and I have a .dic file that contains over 100.000 words and so what I want is a Javascript function that going to check the user input and compare it to all the words in the .dic file and finally return true or false depending on the response?

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Typo.js, but I didn't understand it well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I literally don't know what to tell you.

Comment: I have given you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets break it down

```
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dictionary;
            
            function load() {
                $( '#loading-progress' ).append( 'Loading affix data...' ).append( $( '<br />' ) );
                
                $.get( 'typo/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.aff', function ( affData ) {
                    $( '#loading-progress' ).append( 'Loading English dictionary (this takes a few seconds)...' ).append( $( '<br />' ) );
                    
                    $.get( 'typo/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic', function ( wordsData ) {
                        $( '#loading-progress' ).append( 'Initializing Typo...' );
                
                        dictionary = new Typo( "en_US", affData, wordsData );
                        
                        checkWord( 'mispelled' );
                    } );
                } );
            }
            
            function checkWord( word ) {
                var wordForm = $( '#word-form' );
                wordForm.hide();
                
                var resultsContainer = $( '#results' );
                resultsContainer.html( '' );
                
                resultsContainer.append( $( '<p>' ).text( "Is '" + word + "' spelled correctly?" ) );
        
                var is_spelled_correctly = dictionary.check( word );
                
                resultsContainer.append( $( '<p>' ).append( $( '<code>' ).text( is_spelled_correctly ? 'yes' : 'no' ) ) );
                
                if ( ! is_spelled_correctly ) {
                    resultsContainer.append( $( '<p>' ).text( "Finding spelling suggestions for '" + word + "'..." ) );
                    
                    var array_of_suggestions = dictionary.suggest( word );

                    resultsContainer.append( $( '<p>' ).append( $( '<code>' ).text( array_of_suggestions.join( ', ' ) ) ) );
                }
                
                wordForm.show();
            }
        </script>
```

Here is step one:
you are load typo.js and Jquery for dom manipulation.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="typo/typo.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then step two the main function is load please read through comments in code:

```
function load() {}
```

Lets populate construct load function which uses jquery $.get function

```
$.get( 'file path over the internet', function ( callback ) {});
```

you tell $.get what file to download into DOM and then give call back which will run when process is complete. So as call back with in $.get callback there is another $get with its own callback. So we have nested operations as below;

```
$.get( 'first file', function ( callback on first file ) {
$.get( 'second file', function ( callback on second file ) {});
});
```

This is the whole mechanism of that get files ready for reading.
lets do actual code.

```
//create variable while will hold dictionary data

    var dictionary;
    
    function load() {
    //first file                
    $.get( 'typo/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.aff', function ( affData ) {
    //second file       
    $.get( 'typo/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic', function ( wordsData ) {
    
    //assign data to variable using typo object
    dictionary = new Typo( "en_US", affData, wordsData );
    
    //then finally do the search trough another custom function                 
    checkWord( 'check me' );
                        } );
                    } );
                };
```

Check word is a simple UI function making it do interaction with screen

```
    function checkWord( word ) {
// find wordfrom is from in the web page
var wordForm = $( '#word-form' );

// initially hiding the form when function is called
wordForm.hide();

// prepare div where to show results and clear everything in it
                    
var resultsContainer = $( '#results' );
resultsContainer.html( '' );

// then populate it with some form of indication ohh was it spelled right or what ever

resultsContainer.append( $( '<p>' ).text( "Is '" + word + "' spelled correctly?" ) );
            
// this is your truthy 
// we are going to call the fucntion from typo js through object we created on dictionary variable. moment of truth. It will return true or false. 

var is_spelled_correctly = dictionary.check( word );
// next we chow it to the world by appending Paragraph with text
// what it is doing is running ternary function a short hand for if else e.g. your condition ? 'show yes if meets': 'show no otherwise';
//based on truthy we ran above if its true it will show yes else no. Just visual gimmic.

resultsContainer.append( $( '<p>' ).append( $( '<code>' ).text( is_spelled_correctly ? 'yes' : 'no' ) ) );
//next if it was not spelled correctly run suggestion, based on truthy we ran above if its false run suggestions. Just visual gimmic.           

if ( ! is_spelled_correctly ) {
resultsContainer.append( $( '<p>' ).text( "Finding spelling suggestions for '" + word + "'..." ) );

var array_of_suggestions = dictionary.suggest( word );
resultsContainer.append( $( '<p>' ).append( $( '<code>' ).text( array_of_suggestions.join( ', ' ) ) ) );
                    }
//in the end show form again.                   
                    wordForm.show();
                }
```

on the form in the web page you are calling the function and return false in the end stops it fro running to the internet.

```
<form method="GET" action="" onsubmit="checkWord( document.getElementById( 'word' ).value ); return false;
```

load function was called before hand on page load meaning when page is being rendered

```
<body onload="load();">
```

you could have called in the script it self its just preference.

Hope this gives some understanding. for typo to run you need to files .aff and .dic thats why two gets so run them in nested fashion when one is loaded only then load the other.

We call check function after its all done and from there on we just call the function because everything is in global scope.
did you notice var dictionary was out side of function so bascially it was in global scope accessible to any other functions so we dont have to run load function over and over again.
simple call check function to run the UI as everything else is ready

view-source:https://www.chrisfinke.com/files/typo-demo/

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would tell you to construct/convert the .dic file in alphabetical order for quicker search. Your function is going to read user input (Textfield, , whatever you want), read the file and store values in a data structure (map, array, 2D array or even object), then base on the first letter (again, this is just the basic) in the input you are going to have faster lookup to the partition that holds the result. Ex: user types in "avalanche", you have a dic array converted from file like [{"a": ["am","an","avalanche"...]}, "b": ..., "c"..., ... "z": ...], you know that the result is going to be in the first element which starts with "a" then continue to find matching words in ["am","an","avalanche"...].